# oracle distinct doing sort

Tags: oracle, performance

I'm getting poor performance from DISTINCT.  The explain plan indicates that it is doing SORT (GROUP BY) which doesn't sound right.  I would expect some kind of HASH aggregation to produce much better result.  Is there a hint to tell oracle to use HASH for DISTINCT rather than sort?
I've used /*+ USE_HASH_AGGREGATION */ in similar situations, but it is not working for DISTINCT.

So this is my original query:

```
SELECT
count(distinct userid) n, col
FROM users
GROUP BY col;
```

users has 30M rows, each userid is there 12 times.  This query takes 70 seconds.

Now we rewrite it as

```
SELECT
count(userid) n, col
FROM
(SELECT distinct userid, col FROM users)
GROUP BY col
```

And it takes 40 seconds.
Now add the hint to do hash instead of sort:

```
SELECT
count(userid) n, col
FROM
(SELECT /*+ USE_HASH_AGGREGATION */ distinct userid, col FROM users)
GROUP BY col
```

and it takes 10 seconds.

If somebody can explain to me why this is happening or how I can beat the first simple query into working as good as the 3rd one, that would be fantastic.
The reason I care about query simplicity is because these queries are actually generated.

Plans:
1) Slow:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation      | Name          | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem | Used-Tmp|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |               |      1 |        |      5 |00:01:12.01 |     283K|    292K|       |       |      |     |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY     |               |      1 |      5 |      5 |00:01:12.01 |     283K|    292K|   194M|   448K|  172M (0)|   73728 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| USERS |      1 |     29M|     29M|00:00:08.17 |     283K|    283K|       |       |      |     |
```

2) Fast

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name          | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |               |      1 |        |      5 |00:00:13.09 |     283K|    283K|   |   |      |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY       |               |      1 |      5 |      5 |00:00:13.09 |     283K|    283K|  3072 |  3072 | 2048  (0)|
|   2 |   VIEW               |               |      1 |   8647K|   2445K|00:00:13.16 |     283K|    283K|   |   |      |
|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE       |               |      1 |   8647K|   2445K|00:00:12.57 |     283K|    283K|   113M|    10M|  216M (0)|
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| USERS         |      1 |     29M|     29M|00:00:07.68 |     283K|    283K|   |   |      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you running them one after the other in the same system?  What happens from a performance perspective if you run them in a different order?

Comment: I've been running them in different order.  Also I'm pretty much the only user on the system and it has over 100Gb of RAM so all of this crap should be in cache.

Answer (score 4):

Can you add indexes? I would first try adding an index on `(col, userid)`.

10 seconds looks too much for a 30M rows table.

Comment: 10 seconds is what the full table scan takes.  You think this is too much?  I doubt and index would actually improve things considering the whole table needs to be read anyways?

Comment: If you select only `col` and `COUNT(DISTINCT userid)` it will only read the index.

Comment: @MK01 Why would it need to read the table at all with such an index?  Are there other columns you left out of your examples?

Comment: Index slows it down by 1 second.

Comment: I'm no expert in Oracle. But I've run more complex aggegate queries in MySQL (which is not an enterprise DBMS), in tables of 100M+ rows in less than 1 sec. 10 secs seems too high for sucha simple quey when an idex is there.

Comment: @ypercube oh, so now I'm depressed.

Comment: I think you should add in the description of your question the table's definition and the query plan.

Comment: @ypercube I've added the plans.  The table definition is boring, both userid and col are VARCHAR2s.  There is a bunch of other columns but they do not seem relevant.

Comment: Well, the lengthy columns is probably the explanation why the optimizer does not use the index. Please add, at least the related columns (`VARCHAR2(100)` or `VARCHAR2(5000)`?) and the indexes you have. I'm sure someone with more experience in Oracle will find this useful so they can answer.

Comment: @ypercube oh if I add index it uses it, but it doesn't make things faster.  Well, the full story is that it does, if the table is wide (lots of columns).  But if there are only a couple of extra columns index only slows things down.  userid is VARCHAR2(255) and col is VARCHAR2(16).

Comment: So, if you run your Query-1 (as it is, no additional columns) while having the index, takes more than 70 seconds?

Comment: Yeah, it does FAST FULL SCAN and takes a little over 70 seconds.  It is all spent in CPU sorting the data instead of doing the aggregation like it should.  If I add a bunch of columns, the fast query slows down. Then if I add index, it goes back to being fast.

Answer (score 1):

Is hash group by aggregation disabled for your system or session?  Does this query return FALSE:

```
select value from v$parameter where lower(name) = '_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled';
```

The hint `USE_HASH_AGGREGATION` will still work if the parameter is FALSE, but queries will never use HASH GROUP BY.

---

If it's not disabled, you probably *should* disable it.  I think hash group by aggregation is just completely broken, and should never be used.  It returns wrong results, and can throw ORA-600 errors if you use lots of memory.

For example, see bug "4604970: WRONG RESULTS...".  Supposedly fixed in 11.1.0, but it's still broken.  Try this query:

```
select stddev(test), count(distinct test) from
(
    select 7/9 test from dual
    union all
    select 7/9 test from dual
);
```

If `"_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled"=false;` it will return 0 and 1.  If it's set to true, it will fail with `ORA-01428: argument '-.00000000000000000000000000000000000001' is out of range`.  This is because the values are just slightly off.  I've tried this on several versions of 10g and 11gR2.

I think this is the worst possible type of bug.  If you're very lucky you'll see an error like the one above.  But most likely all of your results will just be slightly off.

Comment: I can't find any traces of _gby_hash_aggregation_enabled being set anywhere.  However everything indicates that it is disabled.  Your test query works fine on this server and when I try it on another one it chooses hash aggregation and fails like you describe.  This is very depressing because I can't get performance I need out of the SORT aggregation.

Comment: What's different between the two servers?  Anything obvious in v$parameter?  Maybe something like `_hash_join_enabled`=false, or a very low value of `hash_area_size` with `workarea_size_policy` set to MANUAL?

Comment: So there are 2 servers, let's call them prod and dev: prod={Enterprise; workarea_size_policy=AUTO; uses hash agg}, dev={Standard, workarea_size_policy=MANUAL; hash_area_size=2,048,000,000; doesn't use hash agg}.

Comment: Maybe the difference between sorting and hashing algorithms is only indirectly related to the problem.  There are some times when SORT GROUP BY performs better than HASH GROUP BY.  Maybe this is one of those times, but something else is slowing the first query down.  Both queries try to use roughly the same amount of memory, but the first query can't fit everything in memory and has to write to temp.  Why can't SORT GROUP BY use more memory?  What is the value of `sort_area_size`?

Comment: Interestingly, the dev server has sort_area_size set to 1024,000,000.  As compared to the prod with 65,536 which sounds ridiculous?  So perhaps dev server picks sort because it has so much memory assigned to sort area.  Except is still makes no sense because everything points out to hash being faster.

Comment: If sort_area_size is set so high on dev, why did the query use temp?  You may want to try playing with the memory settings at the session level to see if you can get the SORT GROUP BY to work entirely in memory.  Writing to disk is probably a much bigger factor than sorting vs. hashing.

Comment: wait, how do you know that SORT query uses temp?

Comment: Used-Tmp = 73728 (which is really 73,728 * 1024 bytes)